# Scala: large calculation losing value to zero/infinity

Tags: scala, nlp, bigdecimal

I'm trying calculate a perplexity value for a language model and the calculation uses a lot of large powers. I have tried converting my calculation to log space using BigDecimal, but I'm not having any luck.

```
var sum=0.0
for(ngram<-testNGrams)
{
  var prob = Math.log(lm.prob(ngram.last, ngram.slice(0,ngram.size-1)))
  if (prob==0.0) sum = sum
  else sum = sum + prob
}
Math.pow(Math.log(Math.exp(sum)),-1.0/wordSize.toDouble)
```

How can I perform such a calculation in Scala without losing my large/small values to zero/Infinity? It seems like a trivial question but I haven't managed to do it.

In the above, you can assume that the method lm.prob issues the correct probabilities between 0 and 1, this has been amply tested.

Answer (score 1):

Write everything in terms of log probabilities, not probabilities.

For instance, things like `log(exp(sum))` just warm up your CPU while throwing away useful information.  Avoid!

If you must convert to actual probabilities, do so at the very last step you can.

Comment: As you can see, I'm trying to use the log probs up until the last line, where I need to get the value for the perplexity.

Comment: @user3297367 - I'm not quite sure how that is supposed to be the perplexity.  There's no `log(exp(sum))` term (that's just the identity function anyway).  Are you trying to use `pow` to do the `-1/N` exponent?  How about just `-sum/N`?  But then you need to raise something to that power (and it's not the sum that you raise to that power typically?).  It's also more typical to use log base 2 than base e.